# LaTEX - Removing item dot and align them

Tags: alignment, latex, indentation

I am working on a LaTEX document where I have a nested list like this:

> - A
>
>   > - a
>   > - b

The code now works fine, it's like:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
        \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

But I want to remove the dot before A. So I did the following:

```
\begin{itemize}[]
    \item A
        \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

It works. But the indentation is still there (though the dot is removed) like below:

> (space for dot) A
>
> > - a
> > - b

I want to also remove the indentation of A like:

> A
>
> > - a
> > - b

Is there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With `\usepackage{enumitem}` you can use

```
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0]
      \item[] one 
      \begin{itemize}
          \item a
          \item b
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
```

Comment: This only makes the `item a b` aligned to `item one`. But what I tried to do is make `item one` align to left and remove the space of dot of `item one`. I was able to solve by having `[leftmargin=0]`. Thanks.